# Camel FTP consumer with move and streamDownload issue?

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have an issue with the FTP2 consumer (Camel 2.19.3) failing to move files after processing them when the `streamDownload` property is enabled. When it's set to `false` the route works as expected but when the property is `true` Camel fails to move the file(s).

The route configuration (Java DSL) looks like this:

```
from("ftp://{{ftp.username}}@{{ftp.host}}/{{ftp.path.in}}"
        + "?password={{ftp.password}}"
        + "&initialDelay={{ftp.check.startdelay}}"
        + "&delay={{ftp.check.delay}}"
        + "&passiveMode=true"
        + "&autoCreate=false"
        + "&startingDirectoryMustExist=true"
        + "&move={{ftp.path.out}}/${file:name}"
        + "&stepwise=false"
        + "&streamDownload=true"
)
.to("log:com.example.camel?level=info")
.to("mock:aMockEndpoint");
```

and here's an example of the error message I'm getting:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot rename file: RemoteFile[abc123a.csv] to: RemoteFile[/reports/archive/abc123a.csv]
```

Here's a Wireshark capture that shows the interaction of a failed run when the `streamDownload` setting is `true`:

```
Response: 220 (xxx)
Request: USER xxx
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Request: PASS xxx
Response: 230 Login successful.
Request: TYPE A
Response: 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Request: SYST
Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Request: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,10,108,120).
Request: LIST reports/incoming
Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
FTP Data: 69 bytes
Response: 226 Directory send OK.
Request: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,10,234,184).
Request: RETR reports/incoming/abc123a.csv
Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for reports/incoming/abc123a.csv (21 bytes).
FTP Data: 21 bytes
Request: DELE /reports/archive/abc123a.csv
Response: 226 Transfer complete.
Response: 550 Delete operation failed.
Request: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
Request: CWD /reports/archive
Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
Request: RNFR reports/incoming/abc123a.csv
Response: 550 RNFR command failed.
Request: QUIT
Response: 221 Goodbye.
```

It seems like Camel is trying to delete and rename the file while it's still locked by the FTP server (i.e. being consumed by the route).

Now here's a Wireshark capture of a successful run after changing the `streamDownload` setting to `false`:

```
Response: 220 (xxx)
Request: USER xxx
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Request: PASS xxx
Response: 230 Login successful.
Request: TYPE A
Response: 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Request: SYST
Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Request: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,10,253,94).
Request: LIST reports/incoming
Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
FTP Data: 69 bytes
Response: 226 Directory send OK.
Request: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,10,125,167).
Request: RETR reports/incoming/abc123a.csv
Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for reports/incoming/abc123a.csv (21 bytes).
FTP Data: 21 bytes
Response: 226 Transfer complete.
Request: DELE /reports/archive/abc123a.csv
Response: 550 Delete operation failed.
Request: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
Request: CWD /reports/archive
Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
Request: CWD /
Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
Request: RNFR reports/incoming/abc123a.csv
Response: 350 Ready for RNTO.
Request: RNTO /reports/archive/abc123a.csv
Response: 250 Rename successful.
Request: NOOP
Response: 200 NOOP ok.
Request: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,10,168,183).
Request: LIST reports/incoming
Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response: 226 Directory send OK.
Request: QUIT
Response: 221 Goodbye.
```

BTW: Changing `stepwise=true` makes no difference if you're wondering.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug or am I trying to do something Camel doesn't support?

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Is this some dummy FTP server or do you use a real external FTP server? I would be a bit surprised that a stream download would lock the remote file on the remote FTP server. Also try to look at the documentation / javadoc for the FTPClient API that Camel uses under the hood for FTP activity to see what they say about using stream download, and potential locking problems

Comment: Hi Claus, it's a real FTP server - vsftpd running on an external Ubuntu server. Also, I have looked at the API docs and got nothing from them but I will go back and look again in case I've missed something.